# Como devo acessar o conteúdo de um JTextField?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, swing, encapsulamento

Em um projeto java **sem conexão com Banco de Dados** onde temos apenas as camadas *Model, View* e *Controller*, qual seria a forma mais adequada de pegar uma `String` que está contida num `JTextField` de uma classe ?  Por Exemplo, temos um campo de texto na camada *View* :

```
JTextField txt = new JTextField("Teste");
```

Suponhamos que eu queira pegar esse texto na camada *Controller*, uma das alternativas seria tornar o `txt` um objeto público, ou gerar o seguinte método na classe do mesmo :

```
public String getTxt() {
        return txt.getText();
    }
```

Fico em dúvida em qual das duas formas usar, já que a primeira traz certa vulnerabilidade ao encapsulamento da aplicação, e a segunda maneira me parece meio "feia" de se fazer. Qual seria a forma mais correta de fazer isso ?

Comment: Swing por si já é uma aplicação de mvc, "reinventar a roda" é totalmente desnecessário. Se já existe o método ali, pra que criar outro? E componentes de tela não precisam desse tratamento todo, já que só serão acessados pela propria class de janela.

Comment: @diegofm Então cara, mas eu fico meio confuso com isso, porque falam que a camada _View_ não pode "conhecer" a camada _Model_ ... Eu no caso quero pegar o texto de certo `JTextField` para comparar com os dados de um ArrayList que fica no _Model_, como fazer isso na própria classe da janela ? '-'

Comment: Isso ta me cheirando a "validação", se for, é pra isso que existem os listeners. Eles são como a camada de controllers, neles é que você valida os componentes, envia dados para o banco, retorna status pra tela e etc. Não posso te dar uma resposta pois a pergunta está meio ampla e baseada em opiniões;

Comment: @diegofm Então vc quer dizer que numa validação que dependa de um dado gerado por uma janela, a forma mais apropriada para fazer essa validação seria na própria classe da janela ? Mesmo que o objeto que armazena seus dados esteja numa camada diferente da _View_ ?

Comment: Nada te impede de separar os listeners em classes separadas, eu já acho que, dependendo do tipo de validação, as vezes é melhor trabalhar com estados, tipo, senha e login são válidos, eu mando eles para o model através de algum listener, e o model me retorna se é valido ou nao. Bom, não da pra aprofundar, talvez você editando e dando um exemplo mais plausível, dê pra elaborar alguma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o melhor seja usar um modelo de eventos. Por exemplo:

```java
public class MeuEvento {
    private final String nomeInformado;

    public MeuEvento(String nomeInformado) {
        this.nomeInformado = nomeInformado;
    }

    public String getNomeInformado() {
        return nomeInformado;
    }
}
```

```java
public class MinhaView {
    private final JFrame frame;
    private final JTextField nomeInformado;
    private final JButton botaoOk;
    private final List<Consumer<MeuEvento>> listeners;
    // ...

    public MinhaView() {
        this.frame = new JFrame();
        this.txt = new JTextField("Teste");
        this.listeners = new ArrayList<>();
        this.botaoOk = new JTextButton("Ok");

        // blablabla...

        this.botaoOk.addActionListener(evt -> {
            MeuEvento me = new MeuEvento(txt.getText());
            for (Consumer<MeuEvento> e : listeners) {
                e.accept(me);
            }
        });
    }

    public void addMeuEventoListener(Consumer<MeuEvento> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeMeuEventoListener(Consumer<MeuEvento> listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

```java
public interface MeuModel {

    public void nomeInformado(String nome);

    // Mais um monte de outros métodos...

}
```

```java
public class MeuController {

     public MeuController(MeuModel model) {
         MinhaView v = new MinhaView();
         v.addMeuEventoListener(m -> model.nomeInformado(m.getNomeInformado()));
     }
}
```

Ao utilizar este formato os eventos disparados pela *view* sejam diretamente remetidos ao *model*, sendo o *controller* apenas responsável por fazer a tradução/adaptação deles. Os eventos em si servem para trafegar dados entre a *view* e o *controller* (mas poderia ser também diretamente entre a *view* e a *model*, com a desvantagem de que a *model* receberia eventos ao invés de apenas responder a chamadas normais de métodos).

Caso existam várias possíveis ações que a tela possa realizar refletindo-se em diferentes ações na *model* (não necessariamente relacionadas de 1-para-1), haverá uma classe de evento para cada uma delas, de forma que cada evento transportará os dados que lhe são convenientes/necessários.

Comment: Isso que você montou é uma variação do padrão observer? ;Se parece muito com algo que estava lendo esses dias.

Comment: @diegofm Sim, é uma implementação do padrão Observer.